# How to specify the Content-Type of an Athena query result file for Java SDK query execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-athena, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I'm executing a query from my Lambda similar to the example provided in the documentation:

```
QueryExecutionContext queryExecutionContext = new QueryExecutionContext().withDatabase(dbName);

ResultConfiguration resultConfiguration = new ResultConfiguration().withOutputLocation("s3://" + resultBucket + "/");

StartQueryExecutionRequest startQueryExecutionRequest = new StartQueryExecutionRequest()
        .withQueryString(queryString)
        .withQueryExecutionContext(queryExecutionContext)
        .withResultConfiguration(resultConfiguration);

StartQueryExecutionResult startQueryExecutionResult = client.startQueryExecution(startQueryExecutionRequest);
```

As expected, a csv file is created in the result bucket that contains the selected rows. It's Content-Type is binary/octet-stream. Is there any way to make Athena create that file with type text/plain?

Comment: did you got any solution for this?

Comment: no, don't think I did